# I lost my changes on github without pull request

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-pull

I worked on github
I changed some code 
I did a ‘’’git push’’’ to master
I forgot to ask a pull request. 
Then, I did a ‘’’git pull —rebase origin master’’’

and so on my branch now I don’t have anymore all my previous code but I could see my changes on github.com

I tried to push again
then I couldn’t see anymore my changes on the GitHub homepage.

The problem is that I need to find my previous code. 
Can anyone help please ?

Comment: `and I obviously lost all my previous code` ... to the contrary, all your commits should still be right there on the top of your local branch.

Comment: Thank you Tim for your answer. That’s a good new ! Can you help me to take it back ? I’m really new on github I struggle to use it lol

Comment: Which work are we talking about here?  Did you commit your work already, or did you have unsaved work?

Comment: I pushed my changes but I forgot to make a pull request so I’m not sure that I committed it

Comment: Please edit your question and give the _exact_ steps you have done.  Don't leave anything to guessing.

Comment: I tried my best to explain the process I made, I hope it’s better now. I’m really new so I still try to understand my self what I’m doing. I hope someone can help

Comment: OK are you using the Git bash, and do you recall doing `git add` or `git commit` ?

Comment: I use the terminal of vs code and I didn’t use  « git add » or « «git commit ». I only did a git push